# What does "slap" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english, slang

From [Grace Dent on Television: Harlots, Housewivs and Heroines - a 17th Century History for Girls, BBC4 | The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/tv/features/grace-dent-on-television-harlots-housewivs-and-heroines-a-17th-century-history-for-girls-bbc4-7785748.html):

> They branded Diana, and still do, an hysterical, diva-ish and paranoid woman, but Diana wasn't paranoid about Camilla and the royal unspoken code of marriage, she was absolutely **slap**, bang on.

What does *slap* mean in this context?

Comment: to be bang-on (with slap) means to be exactly right in BrE. His answer was bang on (correct, accurate, good, OK). Usually, it would not have slap with it but since  it does it should be slap-bang on. She was absolutely like she should have been. It's not the best writing in the world...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a thing is **slap-bang on**, it would mean "exactly right". His answer to the quiz was **slap-bang on**.

That said, one would not usually refer to a  person as being: slap-bang on.

Please note: the term is slap-bang [right, as in right in the middle of] and usually referring to a THING, not a PERSON. Slap-bang is used to intensify: the dog was slap-bang in the middle of the road.

The other term: to be bang on means to be right. slap-bang on merely makes it stronger.

So, **if you want to join /bang on/ the verb to /slap-bang/ the adjective, the best way would be: slap-bang on**.

That said, it is very odd to say that: Princess Diana was slap bang-on. The only meaning here would be: She was right about the royal unspoken code of marriage.

That means: **She knew that if Charles could have Camilla, then she Diana was perfectly justified (slap-bang on or right about) about having that lover of hers (I forget this name).**

Comment: James Hewitt, as I recall. I think your point is likely correct, but I did not want to say the part about Diana's affair because it wasn't included. Funny how after so many years I can remember all the details. I am Canadian, not British, but it was always deemed 'newsworthy'.

Comment: Well, it either means she was justified in having her own lover or she knew that Charles had one. Either way, it's not the greatest writing. I guess the unspoken code of marriage is: royals will have lovers. :)

Comment: I'd like to add to this answer that, as a native English speaker, it's quite similar in feeling to the phrase "on point."

Comment: To address your concern that a *person* cannot be "slap bang on."  I believe it is fairly idiomatic to apply an adjective to a person, when one is really referring to that persons' words, opinions, or behaviors.  As examples:  Alice was wrong to have said ...  Bob was naughty when he...  Charlene was inaccurate in the...  Dave was helpful as he ....

Comment: @cobaltduck Yes, it is idiomatic when the antecedent/referent is clear. Here, it is not clear. Her answers were slap-bang on. OK. Not **usually:** She was slap-bang on (unless explained or clear). Ultimately, it just means 100% right. Does it mean: she understood all royals have lovers? Does it mean: It was OK for her to have a lover too as the others had/have. She was right. Fine. We really cannot ascertain with 100% accuracy what it ***really*** means.

Comment: I think the target of the "slap-bang on" refers to Diana **not being paranoid** about Camilla. In other words I think the author is saying "Diana wasn't imagining that her husband was having an affair." More context of the source would help to place this phrase chronologically.

Comment: @O.M.Y.  I really do not agree with that, as there are two prepositional antecedents. Not one.

Comment: @Lambie True, but we all agree this sentence has "arwfull grammer" to begin with. :)

Comment: I don’t find it the least bit unusual or unidiomatic in the context given here. “Diana wasn’t paranoid about Camilla: she was slap bang on” sounds perfectly normal to me. I perceive no such notion of it being more idiomatic to refer to someone’s words or actions than the person themself; either is equally natural to me. The antecedent seems completely clear and unambiguous to me in the quote given.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jaquet The correctly cited part of the sentence is: /Diana wasn't paranoid about Camilla and the royal unspoken code of marriage/ not /Diana wasn't paranoid about Camilla: she was slap bang on/. Also, no one said it was not idiomatic.

Comment: I don’t see how that makes any difference. The context makes it amply clear what is being referred to. Diana “spouted off” about Charles having an affair with Camilla and how this was part of an unspoken code of marriage with royalty, and she was being realistic, not paranoid, in saying that. There is no ambiguity, and the antecedent is abundantly clear. And no, you did not use the word ‘unidiomatic’, but saying “one would not usually refer to a person as being: slap-bang on” amounts to the same thing in my view. One very often _does_ refer to a person, not a thing, as being just that.

Answer (score 4):

["Slap-bang on"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/slap-bang) is a BrE colloquialism that means (more or less) "exactly", or "right".  For example:

> They tried to take the tube and landed slap-bang in the middle of the daily rush of commuters.

In this case it means that while Diana was *branded* by the media as "paranoid", she actually was correct that Prince Charles was romantically involved with Camilla.

Comment: I've rarely if ever actually heard *slap-bang **on*** (exactly correct), but it doesn't sound ridiculous, and I'm sure I'd have no problem with the *meaning* in context. I think your example *(slap-bang **in the middle**)* is far and away the most common context, probably followed by *[I ran] slap-bang **into** [him]*. Note that the full OED specifically defines ***slap*** in such contexts as *[colloquial] With, or as with, a slap or smart quick blow; quickly, suddenly, without warning or notice*. So it's more ***suddenly*** than ***very***, which is why *slap-bang on* sounds a bit odd to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it seems most equivalent to "on the nose", at least in this context.  I suppose "slap-bang on the nose" would be redundant.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm not going to argue with people who think *slap-bang on* (not followed by an *object*) is "okay", but my suspicion is they're not as familiar with idiomatic English as they'd like to think they are. To my ear it's an experimental conflation of *to run slap-bang **into** something* and *to be **bang-on*** that doesn't exactly work.

Comment: @FumbleFingers One has to strain mightily to  understand what is being said. That said, one can say: He was 100% right. And here, it means Princess Diana was 100% right. Right about having a lover, just like Charles had Camilla. Slap-bang on is preceded by a noun, and not followed by an adjective. It is an adjective.

Comment: @Lambie: I know exactly what Dent (the writer) means. My point is her use of that particular construction is somewhat flakey, even putting aside the comma instead of a hyphen. It looks typical of a certain type of columnists who overdo their attempts to sound "right on" with their colloquialisms. Btw - adjectival "slap bang on" (assuming we accept it at all) would normally be preceded by a *verb* (often a copula, as She **is** [slap] bang on*), not a noun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There's no point in preaching to the converted. I was just pointing out that you said:  people who think slap-bang on (not followed by an object) is "okay", That was somewhat confusing to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The same OED article also gives as sense 2 “directly; straight” (“A turnstile leading slap away into the meadows”, “We walked slap down to the hotel”). That is the sense of _slap_ being used here in my mind: it is simply an intensifier to _bang on (the money)_. I would not personally use a hyphen here (it misrepresents the intonation), but certainly not a comma either. I agree that _slap bang on_ isn’t a collocation in itself, but apart from _slap_, I can’t think what intensifier I might possible use with _bang on_ (not counting more independent adverbs like _absolutely_).

Comment: Interestingly, if we try with _spot on_ instead, _slap_ does not work at all: “You’re slap bang on!” is fine, but “You’re slap spot on!” is utterly bizarre. And oddly, _bang_ actually works all right there: “You’re bang spot on!” is not as idiomatic as “You’re slap bang on!”, but it doesn’t sound bizarre or ridiculous either. (Google even gives hits for _bing-bang spot on_.)

Comment: @Janus: I know about that ***directly, straight*** definition (it's in the *full* OED as well as the cutdown online free version), but I consider it significant that the last cite in the full OED for that is 1889, whereas today's more common ***slap-bang** [in the middle, etc.]* has last cite 1963. I maintain that Dent's usage is more an *attempt* to sound "hip" than a true reflection of a naturally idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the definition in the Oxford English Dictionary, [Slap](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slap)
, and look in the adverb section you can see definition 1.1.

> 1.1 Exactly; right:

Princess Diana was correct in her suspicions about Camilla Parker Bowles.

Comment: She was slap would not mean she was right.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if this is a personal quote or a misquote because it isn't grammatical.

" They branded Diana, and still do, an hysterical, diva-ish and paranoid woman, but Diana wasn't paranoid about Camilla and the royal unspoken code of marriage, she was absolutely slap, bang on."

They branded and still brand Diana,  **as** an hysterical, diva-ish and paranoid woman. **However**, Diana wasn't paranoid about Camilla and  **in regards to** the unspoken royal code of marriage, she was **absolutely correct.**

"Slap" and "Bang on" are slang expressions that simply mean *exactly correct* (at least in the opinion of the speaker/author).

Comment: Yes, they are two separate terms.

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is *completely* wrong. ***Slap*** here is an optional "prefix" to ***bang on** = exactly right* - introducing a comma makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @FumbleFingers were you commenting to me? comma? I think of 'slap' as an added emphasis. It still means exactly right, though I suppose it could be  "exactly! exactly right."

Comment: I *was*, but at the time I hadn't noticed that there was a comma in the original. Bottom line: I disagree with the comma because it should be a hyphen (or *feasibly* nothing). Plus I don't like the usage *slap-bang on* because it conflates two distinct idiomatic usages, as commented elsewhere.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The entire quote was badly written or misspoken from start to finish. I think the question was not about whether or not it was good English but what it meant. I think most of us agree it was poorly written and/or said.

Comment: "branded as" is not necessary; "branded" is fine, and even preferable. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/brand_2

Answer (score 1):

As a "Yank from across the Pond" it seems to me the UK slang "slap-bang" is akin to our own "dead-center" (fairly self-explanatory). We also have the slang "dead-on" which means *perfection*.

The problem seems to be the conflation of "slap" with "bang on" being a somewhat odd combination as I read it. Over here the closest thing to "slap-bang on" might be "dead-on center" in US slang. This is not a very common usage but you may occasionally hear it none-the-less.

Both would mean "perfectly correct" in the final analysis.